# Is it possible to save datetime to DynamoDB?

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have the next code:

```
users_table = Table(users_table_name, connection=Core.aws_dynamodb_connection)
users_table.put_item(data={
  "login": login,
  "password": hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(),
  "profile": profile,
  "registration_date": datetime.now() # PROBLEM IS HERE
})
```

But when I run it, it fails with error:

> TypeError: Unsupported type "< type 'datetime.datetime' >" for value "2015-01-12 05:02:57.053131"

I've tried a lot of ways, but it seems that it isn't possible to save `datetime` to DynamoDB. Btw it works fine in MongoDB.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Why downvoting? I've already spent about 3 hours to find any example, read a lot of documentation, but haven't seen any info about my question.

Comment: Maybe change type from datetime.datetime to string and then store it to DB?

Comment: @m170897017, no it is not a solution, because I need to find users by range of registration date.

Comment: **See Also**: [What data type should be use for timestamp in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40561484/1366033)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Okay, I see that DynamoDB does not support any date types. So the only solution is to use unix-like time as integer, or save date as string.

[image]

Comment: haha, so the problem really is **datetime** not supported :) and yes I think converting them to String is the way to go

Comment: and you should accept your own answer so others will know why & what solutions they have in the same situation.

Comment: @Alex Krzyżanowski I agree with Anzel. You should accept your answer as the correct answer. It is misleading to see the other answer marked as correct.

Comment: String and Number data types can be used. String when storing ISO8601 format, and Number when storing Epoch time. More info here: https://www.abhayachauhan.com/2017/12/how-to-store-dates-or-timestamps-in-dynamodb/

Answer (score 19):

According to alejandro-franco [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894393/is-it-possible-to-save-datetime-to-dynamodb/46996015#46996015) `.isoformat()` make the trick.

Just tested and this a working example:

```
CustomerPreferenceTable.put_item(
    Item={
        "id": str(uuid4()),
        "validAfter": datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
        "validBefore": (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=365)).isoformat(),
        "tags": ["potato", "eggplant"]
    }
)
```

Comment: Just be aware that datetime.utcnow() does not return a date with timezone information. So while parsing back, you should be knowing that stored information is UTC.  Rather than that I would use datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat(), this way the generated information would be easily parsed with datetime.fromisoformat().

Comment: Or better still, use datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) as preferred in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 14):

According to the documentation: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html

> Date  S (string type). The Date values are stored as ISO-8601 formatted
>   strings.

Comment: where do you see it?

Comment: can you update your answer? if the link doesn't exist: write that you don't see it anymore

Comment: @FredCampos the link exists again! You should edit your answer :)

Comment: This is only for Java.  Not for python.

Answer (score 8):

old post but maybe still interesting ..

What you can do and how it worked for me:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

...

now = datetime.now()
x = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

 table.put_item(
           Item={
               'Index': Index,
           
               'Stamp': x,
               
            }
        )
```

And with adaption to the code above:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

...

now = datetime.now()
x = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

users_table = Table(users_table_name, connection=Core.aws_dynamodb_connection)
users_table.put_item(data={
  "login": login,
  "password": hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(),
  "profile": profile,
  "registration_date": x, 
})
```

My Output

[image: You can see the format in the DB]

Answer (score 4):

Reading the documentation lately, I found the right link to the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html). The recommended way to store date and time data in **DynamoDB** is using **ISO 8601** strings. so the data type is just string.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why datetime isn't supported in DynamoDB, or in fact I have no experience in it neither.

But if you're so insisted in not converting the datetime to string like people suggested, you can convert the datetime to timestamp, and so you can compare with it.

#### updated

And you may want to read this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836600/querying-dynamodb-dy-date), seemed like numeric comparison is the preferred way.

Comment: Thank you for response. I am not sure if it is possible in case of storing date as string to query objects by range. So timestamp is the only solution. Thank's to Amazon ahaha :).

Comment: JSON doesn't specify how a datetime should be represented. DynamoDB has kicked off with support JSON field types.

Comment: Another good reason to store datetimes as a normal epoch-based timestamps is that this is what Time To Live is based on. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use date to find users, you can simply invoke `date()` function. Like this:

```
...
users_table = Table(users_table_name, connection=Core.aws_dynamodb_connection)
current = datetime.now()
users_table.put_item(data={
  "login": login,
  "password": hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(),
  "profile": profile,
  # here use a different name for the entry
  "registration_time": current
  "registration_date": current.date()
})
...
```

Comment: No, it doesn't decide the problem. It throws error because it won't accept standard python date objects. I've edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

These are all the supported types for attribute values in DynamoDB as listed [in their AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html).

> **B** A Binary data type.
>
> Type: Blob
>
> Required: No
>
> **BOOL** A Boolean data type.
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Required: No
>
> **BS** A Binary Set data type.
>
> Type: array of Blobs
>
> Required: No
>
> **L** A List of attribute values.
>
> Type: array of AttributeValue objects
>
> Required: No
>
> **M** A Map of attribute values.
>
> Type: String to AttributeValue object map
>
> Required: No
>
> **N** A Number data type.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No
>
> **NS** A Number Set data type.
>
> Type: array of Strings
>
> Required: No
>
> **NULL** A Null data type.
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Required: No
>
> **S** A String data type.
>
> Type: String
>
> Required: No
>
> **SS** A String Set data type.
>
> Type: array of Strings
>
> Required: No

Answer (score 1):

with DDB2, seems like Instant is now supported.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/tree/master/services-custom/dynamodb-enhanced#changing-update-behavior-of-attributes