# DynamoDB Can't Convert to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the C# Object Persistence model in my application, and am populating the table from an external source. I insert a row with the following date (in a String column): `2018-12-12T22:27:14.73Z`. This is generated from a Timestamp using the following Go code:

```
&dynamodb.AttributeValue{S: aws.String(entity.TimeStamp.UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z"))}
```

However, the DynamoDB Object Persistence model chokes when trying to convert it to a `System.DateTime`, with the following error: `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to convert [2018-12-12T22:27:14.73Z] of type Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Primitive to System.DateTime`

If I let my service write a System.DateTime (using a POCO that contains a DateTime property), it looks something like this: `2018-12-19T07:45:36.431Z`. What am I missing that prevents AWS from properly deserializing my dates? It looks like I'm writing them in the same format that Amazon is writing them?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561484/what-data-type-should-be-use-for-timestamp-in-dynamodb

Comment: @JohnB They are already represented as strings in my table; regardless if my C# or Go code wrote them there. My question is related to why I can't seem to get them back out.

Comment: read how they say they should be formatted using `using ISO 8601` strings

Comment: that's your problem right there...formatting not compatible

Comment: They are ISO 8601 strings, see my examples in my question. Compare this example from the linked post: `2015-12-21T17:42:34Z` to mine: `2018-12-19T07:45:36.431Z`. The only difference is that I have decimal seconds, which seems to be within spec? The ones written by the C# Dynamo Library also include the decimal seconds, so I assumed it was the correct and intended format.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. DynamoDB expects the column to *always* have 3 digits of precision in the fractional part of the timestamp. When I formatted the time from Golang, I used `"2006-01-02T15:04:05.999Z"` as my format string, but this causes `time.Format` to truncate the trailing zeros (when they exist). Changing my time format string to *always* print the full precision, I was able to fix my issues.

That said, the documentation could be a little more clear about this precision requirement. Or the exception could be a little more explicit. Heres hoping this question/answer makes that exception searchable on Google!