# DynamoDB insert timestamps with trigger vs in a put/post request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have two small dynamodb tables with about 10 attributes, I want to add "CreatedDate" and "ModifiedDate" attributes to these. I am trying to decide what would be the best practice to do it with the lowest cost and highest performance, reusability.

First, I was thinking to create a trigger and add these attributes when there is an update or create operation in the table. I like this way because it will be centralized. However, I am not sure if this is the cheapest way to do it, because, after a new item written in the table, this trigger will do another write operation to insert the dates.

Second, just sending these values in the "PUT" request as new attributes. That way, I will have to do only one write operation. The downside of doing this, I will need to update each function writes an item to these tables.

Which way I should go in that case? Are there any better ways to do it or anything I am missing?

Comment: Why not just update the dates whenever you update, on the same update call?

Comment: @Deiv Thanks for the comment. I tried to say this in the second case. Do you think it is not clear enough if you think so I will update it? The advantage of using the trigger is making it more centralized.

Comment: I see your point, but personally I feel the small benefit you get from a centralized functionality is not worth the added cost of essentially doubling your write costs. Also, functionality to update with a date is fairly static and won't change once you implement it, so as long as it's consistent then it should be good that way

Comment: You didn't say which programming language you're using but the Node.js dynogels package has a nice feature where it automatically adds createdAt and updatedAt timestamps if you indicate timestamps:true in your schema.

Comment: @Deiv Ok, this makes sense, then probably I will go with this way. Not sure, if it is right to ask this here, but, any suggestions about the date-time formats for querying better?

Comment: @jarmod this sounds cool, yes, I have lambda functions built with node.js

Comment: Sure, [there's a good post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561484/what-data-type-should-be-use-for-timestamp-in-dynamodb) concerning timestamp format for DynamoDB (so that you can actually query/scan it later if needed)

Comment: @Deiv thanks again, this post is very helpful.