# How can I get item by composite key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

```
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    var params: any = {};
    params.TableName = 'StockDailyCandles';
    var key = { 'symbol': 'AAPL', 'datetime': '640590008898' }; // example timestamp
    params.Key = key;

    var x = await dynamoDB.get(params).promise();
    return (x.Item ? true : false);
```

[image]

The composite key for the table is  symbol, and "datetime"(which is simply a timestamp). Both columns are set as strings in dynamodb.

The error im receiving is : The provided key element does not match the schema

Comment: Yes - it is....

Comment: Doesn't dynamo expect an ISO 8601 string for datetimes if you are passing a string? [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561484/what-data-type-should-be-use-for-timestamp-in-dynamodb)

Comment: Can you update your question with a screenshot of the table config as shown in the AWS console, that shows the primary key? Without seeing that it's hard to be sure that's what your key structure is

Comment: @MarkMeyer That doesnt seem to the issue, even providing the value "test" results in the same error.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - I have the column type set as a string. See the image on the OP.

Comment: Ah, yes that helps. Have you considered writing your params [the way the example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property) does?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try it more like this:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-west-2" });

const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

async function getItem() {
  const params = {
    TableName: "RetailDatabase",
    Key: {
      pk: "jim.bob@somewhere.com",
      sk: "metadata",
    },
  };

  const response = await documentClient.get(params).promise();
  return response;
}

getItem()
  .then((data) =>
    console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)));
```