# DynamoDB get the lasted row by date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that has an article a day and it looks like this.

[image]

I set `date` as a primary key and `post_id` as sort key. I want to make a query that gets the one latest row by `date`. Is it possible to do it with Query? or I have to use Scan and filter that out?

Comment: The only way I'm aware of is to scan it and filter it out after getting the results. But I haven't used DynamoDB queries very much. Mainly get and scans.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836600/querying-dynamodb-by-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, DynamoDB doesn't have aggregate functions such as `min` and `max` like RDBMS aggregate function. However, it does have one feature to get the latest date from table. In order to use that option, the attribute should be defined as `SORT` key. Also, the latest date can be found for the specific partition key only i.e. it does not apply for the whole table, just the chosen partition key.

`ScanIndexForward` can be used to get the latest item for the specific partition key.

> ScanIndexForward — (Boolean) Specifies the order for index traversal:
> If true (default), the traversal is performed in ascending order; if
> false, the traversal is performed in descending order.

In order to use the above option, the table design has to be changed.

> post_id - partition key
>
> date - sort key